# I am creating a Multi Module Site in Maven but the Child to parent index.html link in wrong after build

Tags: maven

I am creating a multi module site . I have used the following plugin

```
<plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.3</version>
             <configuration>
                 <stagingDirectory>${staging.location}</stagingDirectory>
                 <reportPlugins>
                     <plugin>
                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                         <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                         <version>2.4</version>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                         <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                         <version>2.8</version>
                         <configuration></configuration>
                         <reportSets>
                             <reportSet>
                                 <id>non-aggregate</id>
                                 <configuration>
                                     <!-- Specific configuration for the aggregate report -->
                                     <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../generated</sourcepath>
                                 </configuration>
                                 <reports>
                                     <report>javadoc</report>
                                 </reports>
                             </reportSet>
                             <reportSet>
                                 <id>aggregate</id>
                                 <configuration>
                                     <!-- Specific configuration for the aggregate report -->
                                     <sourcepath>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/../generated</sourcepath>
                                 </configuration>
                                 <reports>
                                     <report>aggregate</report>
                                 </reports>
                             </reportSet>
                         </reportSets>
                     </plugin>
```

and specified the staging location to Desktop\MavenTestFile .
I have run Maven call mvn site:site and mvn site:stage . After the build the project documentation is generated and parent to child project links are working fine but child to parent site link is incorrect .  I am not sure parent to child project url's are generated . Child to parent project url is looking for index.html in parent project/index.html where as  index.html is in parentProject/taget/site/index.html and thus unable to redirect to that page.